# Fox Float RP2 rear shock problem - soft run and hiss sound on first 5-10% of travel

Tags: maintenance, full-suspension, shocks

I might have a problem with my Fox Float RP2 rear shock (Giant Reign, 150 mm of travel, bike & shock only 6 months old). When pumped to 200 psi, the shock has a considerably soft run and is making a hissing/sucking noise, both on about first 5-10% of its travel. The rest of shock travel seems to behave OK. What do you think is causing the problem? I read about cavitation (when air/nitrogen penetrates oil chamber) and I think that might be my case. With cavitation, do I need an immediate maintenance or can I use the shock like this for the rest of the year and do the seasonal maintenance afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be possible to give you a 100% answer without opening the shock, but it certainly needs service.

6 months of use isn't a great determining factor for service intervals, hours of riding and type of riding (how big, how dirty) are much more important. Have you rebuilt your air can yet? Do you know how many hours you have on the shock?

You can probably run it for a bit (until winter), but it may or may not make it. Either way, the shock needs rebuilt. Sorry dude.

Comment: I sent the shock to the shop for regular annual service/maintenance - the guy in a shop confirmed the problem I described. I guess it was cavitation. After service the shock is OK again.